# C Store words from a file into a Dynamic allocated array, not storing correctly

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dynamic

If I am dynamically allocating an array of pointers to chars(strings). why I cant place the content of the *word inside a given position in my array like so `array[i] = word` or `array[i] = *word`.

I want to split and store the words in a file into a dynamically allocated array. Is this the right direction or is it done through a 2D array.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

   fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
   size_t size = ftell(file);
   fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
   char *array = malloc(size * sizeof(char)+10);
   char *array2 = malloc(size * sizeof(char)+10);
   fread(array, 1, size, file);
   array[size] = '\0';
   char *word;
   word = strtok (array, " ,.-");
   int i = 0;
   while (i <= 9 && word != NULL ){
      for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         array[i] = *word;
         strcpy(&array2[i], word);
         word = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
      }
      fclose(file);
   }
   for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      printf("array[%d] = %c\n", i, array2[i]);
   free(array);
   free(array2);
   fclose(file);
   return 0;
}
```

text to read.

```
This free test evaluates how well you understand what you
```

current output

```
array2[0] = T
array2[1] = f
array2[2] = t
array2[3] = e
array2[4] = h
array2[5] = w
array2[6] = y
array2[7] = u
array2[8] = w
array2[9] = y
```

What Id like to get.

```
array2[0] = The
array2[1] = free
array2[2] = test
array2[3] = evaluates
array2[4] = how 
array2[5] = well
array2[6] = you
array2[7] = understand
array2[8] = what
array2[9] = you
```

Comment: `array[i] = *word;` What are you trying to do there? `word` is pointer to somewhere inside `array`. And why 10 characters? What's that magic number mean? None of that makes much sense.

Comment: Yes, store the pointer inside the array[i] position. 10 to quickly debug my program, I dont want to iterate through 250 words before exiting the loop.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. `*word` is not a pointer. It is a single `char`. It's not clear at all what you are attempting to do. Please give a complete [mre] as well as the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: @kaylum okay I see, Im new in Stack, I fixed it. I hope its more understandable now.

Answer (score 1):

You need two different arrays

The first is the buffer you read the data into - lets call that 'buffer', its a char*

The second is an array of pointers to 'strings' - lets call that 'words' its a char**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE* file = fopen("dict.txt", "r");

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* buffer = malloc(size * sizeof(char) + 10);
    char** words = malloc(sizeof(char*) *  10);
    fread(buffer, 1, size, file);
    buffer[size] = '\0';
    char* word;
    word = strtok(buffer, " ,.-");
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 9 && word != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            words[i] = word;
            word = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf("array[%d] = %s\n", i, words[i]);
    free(buffer);
    free(words);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

I will comment on the complete lack of tests to check if anything worked, PLus I have hardcede to 10 words - since you have done that in the loop it seems.

Also note that the 'words' array if full of pointers to the 'buffer'. If you delete or change 'buffer' 'words' will be invlaid

Comment: Very appreaciated!, Ill analyze it try to understand it.                                                                      Is this how youd have proceed it as well? Im not                                      sure If I should used a pointer to word and a buffer. Or if I should(if its possible) to directly read from the file and store the words, instead of storing the whole text inside a buffer first.

Comment: @LIsa , remeber its hard for us to know what to advice because we dont know your intent, what do you plan to do with the words you read, do you need a lot of them in memory all the time, or just a line at a time. ...... If you just want to read words from a file forever just use scanf %s

Comment: @LIsa also not clear why you have 2 loops, the outer loop will only run once because word == NULL once the inner loop completes

Comment: Yes Ill be given a lot of words and then to delete the repetitions then sort in alphabetical order having them in an array is what I need. Just wondering if youd have stored them in a buffer :) but I get what you mean. Thanks a lot